# NSIS read value from listbox and write it to registry

Tags: listbox, registry, nsis

I’ve been struggling for a while with NSIS, I need a listbox filled with 300 values like

Value     Label

Then take selected value and write it to registry. So far I was able to create the listbox but hadn’t luck getting selected value. Any idea or example. Thanks

Comment: It depends on which dll you're using for your custom listbox (e.g., nsDialogs, InstallOptions, InstallOptionsEx, EmbeddedLists, etc.)  I found EmbeddedLists to be the easiest for me, especially as I also wanted a TreeView, but they all seem to have benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: I’m currently using nsDialogs but willing to switch if needed or find out how to do it in any other way

Comment: For nsDialogs, you use
`${NSD_LB_GetSelection} listbox_HWND $output_variable`
and then you'd use `WriteRegStr`

If you want further help, it would help to post some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Var ListboxValue

Function .onInit
StrCpy $ListboxValue "xyz" ; Default value used in silent installers
FunctionEnd
    
Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page InstFiles

!define LISTITEMSEP ": "
Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateListBox} 0 0 100% 50% ""
Pop $1
${NSD_LB_AppendString} $1 "Foo${LISTITEMSEP}Bar"
${NSD_LB_AppendString} $1 "Hello${LISTITEMSEP}World"
${NSD_LB_SetSelectionIndex} $1 0 ; Select the first item by default
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
${NSD_LB_GetSelection} $1 $2
; Extract the part after the separator
StrLen $3 "${LISTITEMSEP}"
StrCpy $4 0
loop:
    StrCpy $5 $2 $3 $4
    ${If} $5 != "${LISTITEMSEP}"
        IntOp $4 $4 + 1
        StrCmp $5 "" 0 loop
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $4 $4 + $3
    StrCpy $ListboxValue $2 "" $4

${If} $ListboxValue == ""
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "Please select something!"
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section 
MessageBox MB_OK "Write $ListboxValue to the registry here"
SectionEnd
```

You can also use `${NSD_LB_SetItemData}` and `${NSD_LB_GetItemData}` if you need to assign a numeric value to each item.

Comment: Thanks can’t wait to test it!! I’ll post the results as soon as I get home